# Active Caption Text Color — detect change (in .Net)

Tags: .net, windows, user-interface, colors

On Vista, with Aero enabled, the window's title in normal mode has text in black (written over a slightly light glass) while when maximized the title is in white (written over a dark glass).

How can I determine the current color of the window title ?

P.S. I wrote a program to watch after `SystemColors.ActiveCaptionTextColor`, but it remains the same in two modes.

Answer (score 1):

The system color doesn't actually change. What you're seeing is the application of the Aero *theme* to the window. There are themeing APIs available to grab the theme specific colors but my experience has been less than stellar using them.

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS:**
Take a look at the [VisualStyleRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer(VS.80).aspx) and the GetColor method.

Comment: I apply glass effect to all the window.
It displays a pie chart and some statistics, glass effect makes the window look cool and beautiful ... until it is maximized.

The idea is to bind the foreground color of the text to the current color of the caption, which is kept coherent to glass effect.

Comment: The VisualStyleRenderer should help with that.

Comment: Please help me find which one exactly. Either I miss the obvious, or look in a wrong place, or ...

Answer (score 1):

i can't make VisualStyleRenderer tell me anything either.

You can choose between:

- [VisualStyleElement.Window.Caption.Active](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.window.caption.aspx)
- [VisualStyleElement.Window.MaxCaption.Active](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.window.maxcaption.aspx)

Because **MaxCaption** *provides VisualStyleElement objects for each state of the title bar of a **maximized** window.*

Except it doesn't actually work. If you ask for the caption text color of an active maximized window:

```
VisualStyleRenderer renderer = 
   new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Window.MaxCaption.Active);
Color c = renderer.GetColor(ColorProperty.TextColor);
```

It returns **black**, for both **Caption** and **MaxCaption**.

In fact, almost all colors are the same between the two:

[image]

My guess is that there's no way to make your application have the same look and feel as the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to listen for [SystemColorsChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.systemcolorschanged.aspx) event in your form?

```
    SystemColorsChanged += new EventHandler(Form1_SystemColorsChanged);

    void Form1_SystemColorsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //try repainting or refreshing your application
    }
```

I know this is not be the exact solution but you may start working from here.

Comment: I've checked. ActiveCaptionTextColor does not change :(

Comment: ActiveCaptionTextColor contains colors from classic theme, not aero.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `VisualStyleRenderer` based suggestions it might be worth noting, that apparently maximized window captions are handled specially by the Vista DWM (Desktop Window Manager) for performance reasons, see [Raymond Chen's explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/01/8969394.aspx) for (some) details.

Now, I haven't peeked into the Aero theme itself but it might actually define the same TextColor for both the normal and the maximized caption, the latter just not being used by the DWM.

That said I would have guessed that the captions text color in Vista is indeed determined by `VisualStyleElement.Window.Caption.Active` for themed normal windows but the former `SystemColors.ActiveCaptionTextColor` for maximized windows only; unfortunately you figured out already that this is not the case either.

So maybe the DWM just applies an internal default while rendering maximized window captions? If this would be the case you couldn't detect the caption text color change 'by design', rather would need to resort on observing the maximized window state as such and apply the DWM default locally.