# .NET: How to get ActiveCaptionText color when window is maximized?

Tags: .net, winforms, aero, aero-glass, systemcolors

How do you get the [ActiveCaptionText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors_members.aspx) color when a window is maximized?

The color is correct when the window is restored:

[image]

But is the wrong color when the window is maximized:

[image]

How do you get the **active** [ActionCaptionText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors_members.aspx)?

**Note:** Same question for [ActiveCaption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.activecaption.aspx), [InactiveCaption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.inactivecaption.aspx) and [InactiveCaptionText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.inactivecaptiontext.aspx).

---

It seems like there should be something with:

```
VisualStyleRenderer vs = 
   new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Window.MaxCaption.Active);

label1.ForeColor = vs.GetColor(ColorProperty.TextColor);
```

[But i can't make it work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036934/active-caption-text-color-detect-change-in-net) it returns black for both **Caption** and **MaxCaption**:

[image]

---

### References

- Stackoverflow: [Active Caption Text Color — detect change (in .Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036934/active-caption-text-color-detect-change-in-net)
- MSDN Forums: [How to get maximized text color?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/08f3e139-0a60-4193-ac1f-8fa80ec04029/)

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with Aero theme. It ignores that color in the title bar. Try Windows classic theme.